# C++ ifstream read file contents as parts of N length with right shifting

Tags: c++, file, c++20, ifstream

I'm using C++ 20 with ifstream to read data from file.

For example I have file like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

and for length N = 3 I want output like this:

```
abc
bc\n
c\nd
\nde
...
ghi
```

(Yes I want to catch end of lines too).

How do I achieve this?

I want to do it somewhat like this but it does not work:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    size_t nlen = 3;
    while (!file.eof()) {
        auto fp = file.cur;
        std::string s{};
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nlen; i++) {
            char c;
            file.get(c);
            s += c;
        }
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        file.seekg(fp);
        file.ignore(); //or any other function to move file pointer only by one;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a code writing service. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

The streaming operator >> will do formatted input.

 Instead you can use

```
istream& istream::get (char* s, streamsize n)
```

to read the n raw character(s).
You can further use

```
istream& istream::putback (char c);
```

to insert any characters back to the stream.

You should be able to achieve your goal using a combination of one or both of these.

Comment: Perhaps you should include an example of what you are describing.